# Есть ли возможность отслеживать создание таблиц CTAS через DDL триггер?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер, oracle12c

Есть DDL триггер на схему. Срабатывает на создание\изменение объектов в схеме.
Обратил внимание, что не срабатывает на:

```
create table as select ...
```

Есть ли возможность отслеживать создание таблиц таким образом?

Comment: Я только что попробовал. `create table dropme1 as select 1 as n from dual;` у меня вызывало срабатывание триггера и логирование. Oracle 11.2.0.4

Comment: @Viktorov странно, у меня на 12с не робит, все логирует, кроме этого события

Answer (score 2):

Есть, триггер на схему [(*system_trigger*)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html) срабатывает также на событие CTAS.

Простейший рабочий пример:

```sql
create or replace trigger ddltrig after create or alter or drop on hr.schema
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('ddltrig: '||ora_sysevent||' '||
        ora_dict_obj_type||' '||ora_dict_obj_owner||'.'||ora_dict_obj_name);
end;
/
SQL>conn hr/hr@server/pdb1
Connected.
SQL> set serveroutput on

SQL> create table t1 as select 1 id from dual where 1=0;
ddltrig: CREATE TABLE HR.T1

Table created.

SQL> alter table t1 add (memo varchar (128));
ddltrig: ALTER TABLE HR.T1

Table altered.

SQL> drop table t1 purge;
ddltrig: DROP TABLE HR.T1

Table dropped.
```